# python logging not displaying %(name)s format property as expected

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, logging

I have some ideas about what is going on but can't necessarily figure out how to fix it.

I have an Abstract Base Class (ABC) that has an attribute of `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`.  This happens in the `__init__`

I then have a concrete class that overwrites the attribute with the same code.  The concrete class also has an import statement of `from ABC import *`.

My question is...
Why are all of my logging statements coming out with the name of the ABC despite the fact that half of them occur in my concrete class.  I'm using a format string that includes `%(name)s` which it pulls from the logger instance above that uses the `__name__` attribute.

Unfortunately I'm on a standalone system so I can't necessarily copy all the code over, but I think I've hit the key elements.  The only other thing that I would add is that the concrete class does call the `super(concreteClass, self).__init__()` but it makes this call prior to running the code that should be overwriting the logger attribute.

```
import logging

class ABC(object)
    def __init__():
        self.logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)
        self.logger.info("hey I'm in the ABC")

class Concrete(ABC)
    def __init__():
        super(Concrete,self).__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getlogger(__name__)    
        self.logger.info("hey I'm in the concrete")

output
 conc = Concrete()
 (DATE) ABC INFO Hey I'm in the ABC
 (DATE) ABC INFO Hey I'm in the concrete
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are writing out your example code, it looks like the two classes are defined in the same file. Is that the case? Because `__name__` will give you the module name, which is essentially the file name. So in that case, the two should be the same

Additional answer after it was verified that they were in different files:

I can't replicate your results. The code you have posted is not actually runnable so it is very hard to locate your bug. I patched up your code until it was runnable and it works fine. Please take a look at what I ended up writing and see if you see anything you might have done differently.

File: my_abc.py

```
import logging

class ABC(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        self.logger.addHandler(ch)

        self.logger.info("hey I'm in the ABC")
```

File: conc.py

```
import logging
from my_abc import ABC

class Concrete(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Concrete,self).__init__()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        # create console handler and set level to debug
        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        # create formatter
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        # add formatter to ch
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)

        # add ch to logger
        self.logger.addHandler(ch)
        self.logger.info("hey I'm in the concrete")
```

File: run.py

```
from conc import Concrete

conc = Concrete()

print __name__
```

When running the above, this is what I get:

```
$ python run.py 
2016-08-03 14:15:56,681 - my_abc - INFO - hey I'm in the ABC
2016-08-03 14:15:56,681 - conc - INFO - hey I'm in the concrete
__main__
```

Comment: So I'm on a standalone system, I cannot port my code over.  I had to write out teh example as close as I code  without spending forever.

They are not in the same file.  They are in separate files.

Comment: ok so from what I can see your code is basically identical to what I'm talking about.  That's very very interesting.  Let me do some further digging into what my code looks like.  Maybe I'm missing something, because the results you are getting are exactly what I would expect to get and I don't seem to be getting.